# Magento 2 - indexer:reindex throws error "Unknown TokenFilter type [phonetic] for [phonetic]"

Tags: magento2.2, reindex, elasticsearch

Have tried below commands provided for similar queries to resolve reindex issue but failed.

```
php bin/magento indexer:info
php bin/magento indexer:status
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php  bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But it does not works  magento 2.2.6 with elasticsearch5.6.9  even tried for elasticsearch2.4.1 it works for few but fails for catalog_product .

Media on my site is not fetched

```
"Product Indexed
Processing product 7272
Product marked disabled because not category found."
"ElasticSuite Category Indexing indexer process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_creation_exception","reason":"failed to create index"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown TokenFilter type [phonetic] for [phonetic]"},"status":400}

ElasticSuite Thesaurus Indexing index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01"
```

If changed to mysql reindex works but images are not stored in media section

[Magento 2 Enterprise: Elasticsearch Indexing Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192927/magento-2-enterprise-elasticsearch-indexing-issue)
Have downgraded 5.6.9 to 2.4.1 but of no use.

Comment: have you found any solution ???

Answer (score 2):

> **Install Elasticsearch Plugin**

**Step-1** : Check **analysis-phonetic** and **analysis-icu** is installed or not.

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin  list
```

**Step-2** : Go to **elasticsearch** folder for install plugin.

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
```

**Step-3** : For install **analysis-phonetic** plugin

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
```

**Step-4** : For Install **analysis-icu** plugin

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
```

**Step-5** : For activate install plugin

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

***Note: If you already installed it and show an error then first remove and reinstall again. Maybe it was fixed after that.***

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove analysis-phonetic

sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove analysis-icu
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with the elasticsearch configuration, the plugin is required, try this out!

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Then try reindexing again.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you need the Smile ElasticSuite plugin. Follow this: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki/ServerConfig-6.x

Answer (score 0):

Its Bit Late But Still Helps lot of people in future

This Error Occurs when your Elasticsearch updates to next release but the [Phonetic & Icu] plugins don't update automatically

Solution

You have to uninstall Previous Version of Plugins

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove 
analysis-phonetic
analysis-icu
```

Install Again so you can get the compatible Version of plugins

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install 
analysis-phonetic 
analysis-icu
```

Restart Elasticsearch

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Verify it

```
http://your_ip_address:9200/
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer of Waqar Ali:

for the users that use evm (elastic version manager)

if the plugins are missing in the elastic search installation you can install them with the following commands:

```bash
cd ~/.evm/elasticsearch 
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
```

for reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/installation.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic.html